Calling convention and stack, returning value from call?
Does anyone know what happens after a call pushes a value on the stack, it is popped off by callee, then the return address is popped off by callee? Perhaps with some assembly?
I think for the following code the return value of fib is then used as an argument passed to plus function. What I’m confused about is fib return value is popped into a register, then somehow that value ends up being pushed on to a stack frame for the next call.
int fib(int n) {
   if (n == 0)
      return 0;
   if (n == 1)
      return 1;
   return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

int main() {
   return fib(3);
}

I’m using the following picture to understand a thread safe way to use the stack and understand that the return value may be in a register for some conventions.

Ref: link

Callees don't pop their args before popping their return address, the stack is random-access so they simply load from it.  Integer return values are returned in a register, not on the stack.  For your example code, https://godbolt.org/z/jb31fhPza is gcc -Og -m32 asm output for 32-bit x86 (where even the first arg is passed on the stack, unlike normal calling conventions for more modern ISAs like x86-64 or ARM).

Are you taking a class that's using LC-3?  The diagram you linked is about that ultra-simplified architecture.  I don't know why they're reserving space in a stack frame for a return value; LC-3 is a register machine (unlike some teaching ISAs that are accumulator machines) so it would be easy to return a value in a register.

It's also weird that they're emphasizing a linked list of activation records aka stack frames, like apparently one IBM mainframe system actually does (allocating in the heap); everyone else just makes them implicit by using the hardware stack pointer (LC-3 R6 like that article says) to reserve space in contiguous stack memory.  By using another register as a frame pointer (e.g. LC-3 R5) saved to a fixed position in the stack frame, that naturally creates a linked list which can be used for a debugger or exception handler to backtrace up the callstack, but it's not needed for normal call/ret.

Ok, at the end of that article they are talking about reserving space on the stack for stack frames with add r6, r6, #negative_number.  And LC-3's function-call instruction (jsr) doesn't push a return address itself, it just writes it to the link register (R7) like on most RISC ISA, unlike x86 where call itself pushes and jumps.

Then somehow that value ends up being pushed on to a stack frame for the next call. - Yeah, the caller loads it into a register, then runs some other instructions to implement the caller part of the next function call, including storing any values you want to pass as args.

But in your case, note that although fib makes 2 calls to itself, neither of the args are return values.  They're values derived from its own incoming arg.  Addition happens after both calls return.  (So it needs to save the first function's return value somewhere, in memory or in a register that's call-preserved in the calling convention you're using.)

Note about thread safe: Each thread has its own stack.

Add option -S to get an assembler listing.

Both conventions exist. For example the x86 has a return, and a return-and-pop instruction https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret . If the callee can pop the parameters, that saves on code size as it is only done in one place. On the other hand, functions with variable number of parameters, like printf, cannot use the "return-and-pop" instruction as the size to pop is not known at compile time.

@BoP how are variable parameters like printf example handled?

@PeterCordes should I open a new question on explanation of assembly code provided? I can read the code and have questions on why particular instruction ordering was used

@notaorb: variadic functions like printf use a caller-pops convention (leaving args on the stack when it returns), even if you compile with a callee-pops convention (like stdcall or fastcall for 32-bit x86) being the default for other functions.  C even requires printf to silently ignore excess args that the format string doesn't reference so even if you wanted to have it calculate the size of args and pop them, that doesn't work.  The caller would have to pass an integer size, at which point it might as well just be the one to run add esp, imm.

@notaorb: This question as posted isn't very clear exactly what you want to know, so if you could focus it down to something more specific about LC-3 that would be a good idea.  You mention thread safety which is a non-problem since each thread gets its own stack.  But what are you asking about the fact that a return value can be in a register?  It just can.    You don't mention LC-3 anywhere except for linking an article about it, so it would also be better to be more explicit about that, or if you happened to find an LC-3 article but are actually interested in ISAs like ARM or x86.

Most LC-3 calling conventions are pile of bloat, passing parameters on the stack when registers are available, same for return value; using frame pointer when not needed..  There are alternatives easily imagined, though none unpublished/unstandardized/inculcated.  I suppose for educational purposes, it can be useful to show frame pointers, etc.. but those teaching this should emphasize that this is not necessarily the only approach.

@ErikEidt understood about use of registers, I wanted to find a way to exclusively use a stack and chose LC3 because it looked this way. Im researching geometric meaning behind the Latin/Greek alphabet and had suspicions some letters like Lambda and Coptic Alpha use a stack for function calls noted in the curly part of the letter where it rolls up.  So my question isn’t entirely focused on most efficient way for a register computer to make a function call.

There is a number of calling conventions in C, most notably cdecl and stdcall.
Under cdecl, the caller is responsible for balancing the stack.
This is done by following every call instruction (to a function accepting at least one parameter) with a stack-balancing instruction that pops arguments from the stack once the function returns.
In x86, this is done with one or two pop instructions, or an add sp, N instruction.
In LC3, this is done with an ADD R6, R6, N instruction.
Under stdcall, it is the callee who is responsible for balancing the stack.
This is done by popping arguments from the stack right before the function returns.
In x86, this is done with a special ret N instruction at the end of the function, which pops the return address from the stack, then pops and discards N bytes from the stack, and then jumps to the return address.
In LC3, either there is no suitable instruction, or I was unable to find such an instruction.  So maybe LC3 does not use stdcall.
x86 assembly provided by Peter Cordes in a comment: https://godbolt.org/z/jb31fhPza
Since you have not specified a "calling convention" for fib(), your compiler uses the default calling convention, which, if you are doing x86, is probably cdecl, but you better check with your compiler.

cdecl is the default calling convention for many (not all) x86-16 and x86-32 compilers. The OP linked to a page regarding the LC-3 architecture so presumably that's what they're targetting.

@interjay thanks, I hope my edits addressed this.

I found description of x86 calling convention here https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html
